# Trying to build plugin for magento: in admin form always return "The block is not valid"

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, configuration

I'm starting with magento and following one book have one problem when tray to see my form in frontend. Always send me the error: **Call to a member function setData() on a non-object** and, the log files says to me "The block is not valid:Mage_Registries_Block_Adminhtml_Giftregistry_Edit_Form"

My code is the next:

File: app/code/local/Mdg/Giftregistry/Block/Registries/Edit/Form.php

```
class Mdg_Giftregistry_Block_Adminhtml_Registries_Edit_Form extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {         

protected function _prepareForm(){       
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',        
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'         
   ));     
    $form->setUseContainer(true);    
    $this->setForm($form);  

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData()){   
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData();  
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(null);       
   }elseif(Mage::registry('registry_data')){
       $data = Mage::registry('registry_data')->getData();   
   }

   $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('registry_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Gift Registry information')));         
   $fieldset->addField('type_id', 'text', array('label'=> Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Registry Id'),'class'=> 'required-entry','required'  => true,'name'=> 'type_id',)); 
   $fieldset->addField('website_id', 'text', array('label'=> Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Website Id'),'class'=> 'required-entry','required'=> true,'name'=> 'website_id',));
   $fieldset->addField('event_location', 'text', array('label' => Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Event Location'),'class'=> 'required-entry','required'  => true,'name'=> 'event_location',)); 
   $fieldset->addField('event_date', 'text', array('label'=> Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Event Date'),'class'=> 'required-entry', 'required'  => true,'name'=> 'event_date',));      
   $fieldset->addField('event_country', 'text', array('label'=> Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Event Country'),'class'=> 'required-entry','required'  => true,'name'=> 'event_country',));
   $form->setValues($data);
   return parent::_prepareForm();        
}    
}
```

And my config to admin part is:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/giftregistry.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>         
        <reference name="left">             
            <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">                 
                <block type="mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry" name="tab_giftregistry_main" template="mdg/giftregistry/customer/main.phtml">                     
                    <block type="mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry_list" name="tab_giftregistry_list" as="giftregistry_list" />                 
                </block>                 
                <action method="addTab">                     
                    <name>mdg_giftregistry</name>                     
                    <block>mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_giftregistry</block>                 
                </action>             
            </reference>         
        </reference>     
    </adminhtml_customer_edit> 
    <adminhtml_giftregistry_index> 
        <reference name="content">              
            <block type="mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_registries" name="registries" />          
        </reference>      
    </adminhtml_giftregistry_index>
    <adminhtml_giftregistry_edit>    
        <reference name="content">     
           <block type="mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_registries_edit" name="new_registry_tabs" />       
        </reference>  
    </adminhtml_giftregistry_edit>
</layout>
```

I check the paths of the files and it's ok but i don't know where it's the error

Thanks for help!

Edit: I'm found other ask like this [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608203/magento-admin-issue) but: a) I don't see the solution and b) in the comments talk about create in Helper/Data.php one class extends to Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract but i have this yet and the problem continues :(

Edit: All my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>        
    <Mdg_Giftregistry>             
        <version>0.1.0</version>         
    </Mdg_Giftregistry>     
</modules>     
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>            
            <mdg_giftregistry module="mdg_giftregistry">                
                <file>mdg_giftregistry.xml</file>            
            </mdg_giftregistry>        
        </updates>    
    </layout>
       <routers>
           <mdg_giftregistry>         
               <use>standard</use>                 
               <args>                     
                   <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>                     
                   <frontName>giftregistry</frontName>                 
               </args>             
           </mdg_giftregistry>
       </routers>
   </frontend>
   <admin>
       <routers>    
           <adminhtml>      
               <args>        
                   <modules>          
                       <mdg_giftregistry before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mdg_Giftregistry_Adminhtml</mdg_giftregistry>        
                   </modules>      
               </args>    
           </adminhtml>  
       </routers> 
   </admin>
   <adminhtml>         
       <layout>             
           <updates>                 
               <mdg_giftregistry module="mdg_giftregistry">         
                <file>giftregistry.xml</file>                 
               </mdg_giftregistry>             
            </updates>
         </layout>
   </adminhtml>
<global>
    <models>             
        <mdg_giftregistry>                 
            <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model</class> 
            <resourceModel>mdg_giftregistry_mysql4</resourceModel>                        
        </mdg_giftregistry>         
        <mdg_giftregistry_mysql4>
            <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Mysql4</class>     
            <entities>             
                <entity>                 
                    <table>mdg_giftregistry_entity</table>             
                </entity>             
                <item>                 
                    <table>mdg_giftregistry_item</table>             
                </item>             
                <type>                 
                    <table>mdg_giftregistry_type</table>             
                </type>         
            </entities>
        </mdg_giftregistry_mysql4>
    </models>         
    <blocks>             
        <mdg_giftregistry>                 
            <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Block</class>             
        </mdg_giftregistry>         
    </blocks>         
    <helpers>             
        <mdg_giftregistry>                 
            <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Helper</class>             
        </mdg_giftregistry>         
    </helpers>         
    <resources>             
        <mdg_giftregistry_setup>                 
              <setup>                     
                <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
              </setup>         
              <connection>
                  <use>core_setup</use>
              </connection>
        </mdg_giftregistry_setup>      
        <mdg_giftregistry_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>            
        </mdg_giftregistry_write>
        <mdg_giftregistry_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mdg_giftregistry_read>
   </resources>   
</global>   
</config>
```

Edit: I saw the anwer from Marius and my Edit.php it's the next:
File: app/code/local/Mdg/Giftregistry/Block/Adminhtml/Registries/Edit.php

```
class Mdg_Giftregistry_Block_Adminhtml_Registries_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container{
   public function __construct(){                      
       parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';   
        $this->_blockGroup = 'registries';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_registries';
        $this->_mode = 'edit'; 
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Save'));  
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Delete'));                 
    }     

    public function getHeaderText(){         
        if(Mage::registry('registries_data') && Mage::registry('registries_data')->getId()){             
            return Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__("Edit Registry '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('registries_data')->getTitle()));        
        }else{
            return Mage::helper('mdg_giftregistry')->__('Add Registry');     
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout(){
    if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
        $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}


}
```

In the book, the values of $_controller and $_blockGroup it's the same... :(

Comment: Please add the config.xml of your module in the question.

Comment: Edit the question...sorry i'm forgot put the config.xml

Comment: See any strange in the code?

Comment: Hey...anybody found the error? I saw my tutorial and the steps are the same... :( :(

Comment: Most probably the error is in the `Edit.php` class of your module. Check the values for `$_blockGroup` and `$_controller` variables

Comment: Thanks for your comment Marius, i saw the file and the values for $_blockGroup and $_controller... and it's the same like the book :S. I put the code in the question ;)

Comment: ¿Somebody found the mistake? I try to changes the values of $_blockGroup and $_controller and isn't works :(

Comment: Anybody? Please....I can't found the solution. I've been reviewing the code who said me Marius, some tutorials more... and isn't works

Answer (score 1):

According to the given code snippets, Magento tries to instantiate a block of the type

```
$this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'
```

which resolves to

```
registries/adminhtml_registries_edit_form
```

There is no block of that type in your codes. There is a block of the type

```
mdg_giftregistry/adminhtml_registries_edit_form
```

but it cannot be resolved (autoloaded) as the corresponding class is not defined in an appropriate file path. It should be located at `app/code/local/Mdg/Giftregistry/Block/Adminhtml/Registries/Edit/Form.php` instead of `app/code/local/Mdg/Giftregistry/Block/Registries/Edit/Form.php`.